# Session variable set in index.jsp returns null when accessed 3rd or 4th time by javascript in others jsp's

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, session-variables, session-timeout

The project is using Spring Framework.

1. Is there a way to extend the session variable timeout ?
2. To make session variable accessible throughout the website ?
   I don't want to set the session variables in the controller.

The flow is as follows :

- '/' i.e. "index.jsp" calls "country.html" if session variable is set to null.
- the user then selects a country in "country.html" and form is submitted to "/index.jsp"
- Then "index.jsp" gets value using"request.getParameter(countryCode)" , if not null then it sets session variable using "objectSession.setAttribute("countryCode", IN);".

Uptil here there is no issue.
But in i click the on other links like "/test.jsp", the javascript in "test.jsp" is returning null for

> var countryCode = '<%= session.getAttribute("countryCode") %>';

Similarly if i click on "/index.jsp" it is redirecting me to "country.html" because

> coun =(String) objectSession.getAttribute("countryCode");

in the scriptlet is null i guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the response.SendRedirect() which was creating a new session on every attempt.
Now i am using controller only but instead of redirect used ModelAndView to get to the desired page.